# PHP won't post form to database

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

Trying to post a simple form to my database but can't get it to work. I have PHP and MySQL activated through XAMPP. The database "E-mail list" is set up with the table "Players".

PHP code:

```
      <?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'E-mail list');
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
    $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $phone = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    $other = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['other']);
    $query = 'INSERT INTO Players (
    name,
    email,
    phone,
    other
    )
    VALUES ('.$name.', "'.$email.'", "'.$phone.'","'.$other.'")';
    if ($mysqli->query($query))
    {
    echo 'Data Saved Successfully.';
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'Cannot save data.';
    }}
    ?>
```

And the form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Please enter your name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required" value="" autocomplete="off" />
    <label for="email">Please enter your e-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required" autocomplete="off"  />
    <label for="phone">Please enter your phone number:</label>
    <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="required" autocomplete="off"  />

<br><br>    
<label for="other">Other comments</label>
<textarea name="other" id="other" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Anything else you'd like to add?">
</textarea>
</form>
<p><strong id="error"></strong></p>
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="save" name="save" value="Submit Form" />
<p id="response"></p>
```

Comment: I suggest a `print_r` on `$query` so that you can verify what you're sending to the database. I'd also highly recommend using parametrized queries.

Comment: all the string values in the querry should use quotes

Comment: Missing `action` in `<form>` , and You have an extra > after `<form>`

Comment: thanks guys! i think the ' in front of INSERT might be the villain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some changes in your codes both PHP and HTML Parts.,

**For PHP :**

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'E-mail list');
/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
}
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$phone = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$other = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['other']);
$query = "INSERT INTO Players (`name`,`email`,`phone`,`other`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$email."','".$phone."','".$other."')";
if($mysqli->query($query))
{
echo 'Data Saved Successfully.';
}
else
{
echo 'Cannot save data.';
}
}
?>
```

**For HTML :**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Please enter your name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required" value="" autocomplete="off" /><br />
    <label for="email">Please enter your e-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required" autocomplete="off"  /><br />
    <label for="phone">Please enter your phone number:</label>
    <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="required" autocomplete="off"  />

<br><br>    
<label for="other">Other comments</label>
<textarea name="other" id="other" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Anything else you'd like to add?">
</textarea>
<p><strong id="error"></strong></p>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" id="save" name="save" value="Submit Form" />
<p id="response"></p>
</form>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Missing double quotes for name value in your SQL.

```
VALUES ("'.$name.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$phone.'","'.$other.'")';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox/firebug to see the parameters and result, and add an echo($query); so you can see it in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

'E-mail list' doesn't seem like convenient database name, though it should be okay.
Anyway, your goal should be to display all possible error that may occur.

So, you have to always check for the errors and report them in more usable form than just 'Cannot save data.'

Always check your connect

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'E-mail list');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    trigger_error($mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

same for the query

```
if (!$mysqli->query($query)) {
    trigger_error($mysqli->error." ".$query);
}
```

If you see no error messages - check the logic of your code: if you ever run the code, if you run the code you wrote, if PHP works, typos etc.